# How to remove specific categories from taxonomy / wp_query?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to remove a specific category from a taxonomy 'product_cat' list in Wordpress. Currently I have a wp_query that displays all product categories but every-time I try and remove a specific category, nothing changes.

The page and category is 'other products' when I know the ID is = 35. The website is: http://gostow.coredigital.info/gostow-configurator/

I have tried various fixes from hooks, to wp_query category__not_in. Everything just doesn't want to work for reason reason so any help would be appreciated.

```
                    <select id="cat-select-box" name="amt_per">
                        <option class="amt-button" value=""'.$selected.'><?php _e("Select the manufacturer of your vehicle..."); ?></option>
                        <?php
                        $product_categories = get_terms(array(
                            'taxonomy' => "product_cat",
                            'orderby' => 'NAME',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
                            'hide_empty' => 1,
                            'category__not_in' => array( 25 ),
                        ));



                        foreach ($product_categories as $term) {
                            $selected = isset($_POST['amt_per']) && $_POST['amt_per'] == $term->slug ? ' selected' : '';
                            echo '<option class="amt-button" value="' . $term->slug . '"' . $selected . '>' . $term->name . '</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
```

The expected output to is hide 'Other Products' from this first dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

I Have now fixed this:

```
    $product_categories = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => "product_cat",
        'orderby' => 'NAME',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => 1,
        'exclude' => array(25,35),
                    ));
```